# Turn off Azure Media Services logo in media player

Tags: azure-media-services

I'm reading the docs for the new Azure Media Player (https://aka.ms/ampdocs) but I still can't figure out how to turn the AMS logo off.  Should I be setting

`amp.Player.LogoConfig.enabled = false`

? That doesn't work for me.  Do I set something on the `<video>` tag?  I can't find a sample that shows me how.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I faced this problem today as well. And here is solution

```html
<video id="azuremediaplayer"
       class="azuremediaplayer amp-default-skin amp-big-play-centered"
       controls autoplay
       width="640"
       height="360"
       poster="<Your poster>"
       data-setup='{"logo": { "enabled": false }, "techOrder": ["azureHtml5JS", "flashSS", "silverlightSS", "html5"], "nativeControlsForTouch": false}' tabindex="0">
    <source src="<Your movie>" />
    <p class="amp-no-js">To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that supports HTML5 video</p>
</video>
```

Hope that help :)

Comment: the key here is ```"logo": { "enabled": false }```

Answer (score 9):

To turn off the logo when setting things up with js you can use the following example.

```
<script>
        var myPlayer = null;

        if (!!myPlayer) {
            myPlayer.dispose();
        }

        var myOptions = {
            "nativeControlsForTouch": false,
            "logo": { "enabled": false },
            autoplay: true,
            controls: true,
            width: "640",
            height: "400",
            poster: ""
        };
        myPlayer = amp("vid1", myOptions);
        myPlayer.currentTime(30);
        myPlayer.src([{ src: "http://amssamples.streaming.mediaservices.windows.net/91492735-c523-432b-ba01-faba6c2206a2/AzureMediaServicesPromo.ism/manifest", type: "application/vnd.ms-sstr+xml" }, ]);

</script>
```

Using the following scripts

```
 <link href="//amp.azure.net/libs/amp/latest/skins/amp-default/azuremediaplayer.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//amp.azure.net/libs/amp/latest/azuremediaplayer.min.js"></script>
<script>
    amp.options.flashSS.swf = "//amp.azure.net/libs/amp/latest/techs/StrobeMediaPlayback.2.0.swf"
    amp.options.flashSS.plugin = "//amp.azure.net/libs/amp/latest/techs/MSAdaptiveStreamingPlugin-osmf2.0.swf"
    amp.options.silverlightSS.xap = "//amp.azure.net/libs/amp/latest/techs/SmoothStreamingPlayer.xap"
</script>
```

and HTML tag looking like this.

```
        <video id="vid1" class="azuremediaplayer amp-default-skin amp-big-play-centered" tabindex="0">  </video>
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `"logo": { "enabled": false }` won't work when using Azure Media Player [v2.0](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/now-announcing-azure-media-player-v2-0/),

So, this CSS hack will do the trick.

```
.amp-content-title {
    display: none;
}
```

**-- Update --**

Or as mentioned in [this comment](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/now-announcing-azure-media-player-v2-0/#comment-3747394576), just upgrade to the version 2.1.2 where this issue was fixed (and the `"logo": { "enabled": false }` should be working fine again)